# React TS - Max character limit for textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I have 2 issues. I've created a textarea component that will also keep track of how many characters the user has typed into the textarea.

**Issue 1:**
I'm trying to see if the current input length the user has typed is more than or equal to(`>=`) my `maxLength` prop `if (value.length >= maxLength)`, but I get this error:

```
var maxLength: number | undefined
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
```

Could somebody explain why I'm getting this?

**Issue 2:**
Currently when you type a single character into the textarea, the character limit will remain at `0`, and will only start to increment after the second character has been typed. Also if you type some text in the textatea and then delete it, it says the character limit is `1/X` when it should be `0/X`. How can I fix this?

**Code:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface ITextarea {
  maxLength?: number;
}

const Textarea: React.FC<ITextarea> = ({ maxLength }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
  const [charLimit, setCharLimit] = React.useState(`0 / ${maxLength}`);

  const handleCharLimit = () => {
    if (value.length >= maxLength) {
      setCharLimit("You have reached the maximum number of characters!");
    } else {
      setCharLimit(`${value.length} / ${maxLength}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <textarea
        value={value}
        onChange={event => {
          setValue(event.target.value);
          handleCharLimit();
        }}
        maxLength={maxLength}
      />
      {maxLength && <span>{charLimit}</span>}
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Textarea maxLength={50} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's a [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-star-2w1gu), forks are appretiated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

`ITextarea` defines `maxLength` as an optional parameter. If you don't pass a value for it, its value will be undefined.

2. This happens because React state updates aren't immediate, they happen on the next render pass. You're calling `handleCharLimit`, but when you invoke it, `value` hasn't actually been updated yet, even though it's called after `setValue`. You should be using `useEffect` or `useMemo` to update your `charLimit` in response to a change in `value`.

See an updated version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-fermi-bsmny

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the speedy response. I think you might have pasted the wrong sandbox link?

Comment: Yes, thanks you! :) I'm still learning React Hooks and React in general, but this works perfectly, I'll need to do some further reading to see how this is working in more detail. I've noticed `maxLength` is still an optional parameter - why isn't this erroing anymore in your fork?

Comment: I'm guarding it in the `React.useMemo` callback by checking `if(maxLength) { ... }`. This lets Typescript know that usage inside of that if statement is narrowed to cases where maxLength is not undefined, so it doesn't complain. useMemo is kind of like useEffect + useState - the function only runs when the dependencies array changes. This makes it ideal for these kind of dependent values.